# Check the folder if the their is a file zip c# then if exist it will automatically move

Tags: c#

Good day,

I have a problem regarding moving the file to other folder.
the scenario is this. Every time i put in the main folder it will automatically copy the file into folder 2.

**(TAKE NOTE AUTOMATICALLY CHECK IF THE FOLDER HAS A FILE THEN COPY THE FILE TO FOLDER 2)**

this is my code

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(filepath, "*exp.zip", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
if (files.Length < 1)
{
   MessageBox.Show("No File");
}
else
{
   // COPY THE FILE TO THE OTHER FOLDER
}
```

THANK YOU GUYS.

Comment: thank @D-Shih i forgot to re arrange

Comment: is it that u want to move all zip files only ? Then i hope my answer would help

Comment: I think he want to copy any zip file to a specific directory as soon as it's placed in a different specific directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is an automatic trigger when any zip file is placed in folder than it automatically get copied.

**MSDN:**

> FileSystemWatcher listens to the file system change notifications and
>   raises events when a directory, or file in a directory, changes.

Check [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) for more detail.

**What you need:**

```
FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher;

private void watch()
{
  fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
  fileWatcher.Path = path;
  fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                         | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
  fileWatcher.Filter = "*.zip";
  fileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
  fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
  //Copies file to another directory.
}
```

Comment: yah thats what i mean

Comment: Please check updated answer. You may need to make some changes as per you need. Please upvote/mark as answer is useful. Let me know if you need anything. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's easy,just need to check for the file extension in the filename :

```
private void Test()
{
var Folder = "FolderPathHere";
var FilesCount = GetFiles(Folder);
foreach (var file in FilesCount)
{
    if (file.Contains("zip"))
    {
    ////ur moving file code here
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It will move file if there is a "zip" in name as well. I think he wants to onlu file zip type.

Comment: I want automatically move my file if i insert a new file to the folder...

Comment: Wait....what do u mean by insert a new file ?? Through ur application or outside ur app ?

Answer (score 0):

```
string fileExtension = "*.zip";//file type

string[] txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, fileExtension);//find all zip files 

foreach (var item in txtFiles)//move all zip files
{

    if (File.Exists(item)
    {

        File.Move(source, destination + item.GetFileName(source));//move the file into destination

    }
    else
    {
        File.Move(source, destination2 + item.GetFileName(source));//move the file into destination

    }
}
```